# Braid group and the fundamental group of coefficients of polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, polynomials, braid-groups

I am studying Norbert A'Campo's article "Tresses, monodromie et le groupe symplectique" and I am trying to understand why $\rho(t_i)=T_i$. I am stating this just for the sake of reference, in principle this is a stand-alone question. Here it goes:

Let n>3 be a natural number. For each $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$, consider the polynomial \begin{equation}f_a(x)=x^{n+1}+\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^{i-1}=\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(x-z_i^a).\end{equation}Define $\Delta$ to be the subset of those $a$ such that $f_a$ has a double root. It is well-known that the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \Delta$ is isomorphic to the Artin braid group $B(n+1)$ on $n+1$ strands. Namely, the isomorphism is induced by the homeomorphism $\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \Delta\to \text{Conf}_{n+1}(\mathbb{C})$ where $a\mapsto (z_1^a,\ldots,z_{n+1}^a)$. The repeated application of a generalisation of the Hyperplane Section Theorem, gives us a line $H\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $(\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\Delta)\cap H\cong \mathbb{C}\setminus A$, where $A$ is a set of $n$ points in the complex plane.
This is the space of coefficients of $f_a$ where we have fixed $n-1$ of the $a_i$ and are letting the remaining one vary. The same theorem also sates that we have a surjective group homomorphism $\pi_1((\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\Delta) \cap H)\to \pi_1(\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \Delta)$ induced by the inclusion.

Now, the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$ is the free group on $n$ generators and we have a composition of group homomorphisms \begin{equation}\pi_1(\mathbb{C}\setminus A)\cong \pi_1((\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \Delta)\cap H)\to\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \Delta)\cong B(n+1)\end{equation}where all the maps are discussed above.

**Question**

I am trying to show that the generator $[\gamma_i]\in \pi_1(\mathbb{C}\setminus A)$, where $\gamma_i$ is the loop going around once around a puncture $p_i$, to mapped to the $i$-th generator $t_i\in B(n+1)$. One thing that I need is that going once around $p_i$ corresponds to permunting the $i$-th and $(i+1)$-th root of $f_a$. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

The line $H$ can be chosen such that $\mathbb{C}\setminus A\cong (\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \Delta)\cap H$ is the space of a single coordinate $a_i$ of $f_a$. In other words, inclusion $(\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \Delta)\cap H\to \mathbb{C}^n\setminus \Delta$ is given by $a_i\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,a_i\ldots,a_n)$ where the $a_j$ for $j\neq i$ are fixed. Might this be a step in the right direction?

Comment: Why does going around $p_i$ permute the $i$-th and $(i+1)$-th roots and not (say) the 1st and $(i+1)$-th?  (In general, the generators should be a collection of $n$ transpositions that are organised in a tree. There is a pretty way to pass between such trees by "detaching and reattaching".  I will guess that this move corresponds to changing the choice of hyperplane in a minimal way?)

Comment: @SamNead Thank you for your comment! I guess you are right about the loop around the $p_i$, they could also do that. Could you spell out your ideas about "detaching and reattaching" a bit more? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \Delta$ the pure braid group? You need to mod out by the symmetric group to get the braid group. When you have a loop in the plane going around, say, the first puncture, you get a square of the usual generator of the braid group. The loops don't permute the punctures.

Comment: @AutumnKent - The poster is working with coefficients, not roots.  Thus they are working in the quotient - that is, the fundamental group is not pure but rather is the entire braid group.  Question: what is the rank of the pure braid group?  I don't think it is generated by the squares of the half-twists...

Comment: @ErikBarinaga - I don't know how to prove what you want.  And now that I think about it, I think that any two generic planes should be connected by a path through generic planes... urk.

Comment: @SamNead - Thank you for your time. I have just edited my question with a new idea, which seems promising. I would be interested in your thoughts!